# Multiple FOR loop flow chart

Tags: r

I am beginner in R and trying to understand multiple FOR loop. I was expecting output will be {6,12} but getting {3,12}. 
x=6(1+2+3)

```
xx <- function() {
    x <- c(0)
    y <- c(0)
    z <- c(0)

    for (i in 1:3) {
        x <- x + 1
        for (k in 1:4) {
            y <- y + 1
        }
        y
    }
    z <- c(x, y)
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect `x` to be equal to `6`?

Comment: It's `x + 1` not `x + i`. Also, I've edited your code because your indentation was a mess. I use package `formatR` function `tidy_source()` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong because if you use x + 1 you will get in step_1 = 0 + 1, step_2 = 1 + 1 = 2, and in step_3 = 2 + 1 = 3, print this last value. Now if you want to get the output (6,12), it would be as follows:

```
x <- y <- z <- c(0)
  for (i in 1:3) {
    x <- x + i
    for (k in 1:4) {
      y <- y + 1
    }
  }
z <- c(x, y)
print(z)
```